# Event horizon area and entropy content of a black hole

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, entropy, event-horizon, holographic-principle

I am aware that the entropy content of a black hole is proportional to the area of its event horizon, and that this can be boiled down to the bit content of a Planck area on the horizon, but I have the following questions about this proportionality:

Does the entropy in some sense *reside* on the event horizon, or is the proportionality just an abstract relationship? And

If the entropy does reside on the event horizon, how is it encoded in the surface area? That is, if there's one bit contained within a Planck area, what differentiates a Planck area that represents a "zero" bit from one that represents or contains a "one" bit?

Comment: *Does the entropy in some sense reside on the event horizon* No one knows. There are many quite different proposals for the description of quantum black hole states all giving the same entropy. This is sometimes referred to as “problem of universality”. For a recent review see Carlip, “Black Hole Thermodynamics” [arXiv:1410.1486](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1486).

Comment: @safesphere, I have learned to stay well clear of the worst of the bunch here- those who are unkind and at times overtly belligerent. When one of those (and you probably know by now who I am referring to) goes up against me in the comments section, I retreat and delete in a heartbeat, especially if they have more rep score than me- which is usually the case with the harsh people. we can discuss this in private if you wish; send me a message thru my website at www.nielsenkillowatt.com and don't lose hope. -NN

Comment: The people who set up this place also control the culture. Explicitly it is: answer the question correctly and that's the only thing that matters. This is not a forum, not a chat room, not a social site. I accept this for the following reasons: 1) I didn't create this site nor do I work to maintain it, instead I follow the rules and 2) once a year I get a message from another user thanking me for my patience in answering his question. And I still play bass on the side, any chance I get